# Move footer to right side container

Tags: html, css

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06pMA.png)

I want my footer to look like the image above.

My code so far:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
}

.nav img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

a {
  font-family: TeX Gyre Termes;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
}

.left img {
  margin-top: 90px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  top: 25px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 75px 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 29px;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.email {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <nav class="nav">
    <img src="logobckgrnd.png" alt="logo">
    <!--fix image-->
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
  </nav>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="logofull.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Welcome to My Portfolio</h1>
      <p> My name is Valentina Nguyen and I'm a recent graduate with a Bachelor's in Business Administration and a passion for marketing. I have been lucky enough to have the opportunity to work in various industries, giving me a well-rounded understanding
        of the marketing world. I am currently in the process of continuing my education to get a Master's in Data Analysis. I use my knowledge of data and analytics to help create effective marketing strategies. Through my portfolio, you can explore
        my professional experience and get to know me better.
      </p>
      <br>
      <p>Feel free to take a look around!</p>
      <a href="portfolio.html" class="button">View Portfolio</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
  <span class="email">valentinajnguyen@icloud.com</span>
  <span class="number">(865) 242-8596</span>
  <span class="copy">©2023 Valentina Nguyen. All right reserved.</span>
</footer>

</html>
```

I need help getting the footer to the bottom right side of the page with spaces in between each element. I also need help figuring out how to make the site resize to whatever display it's on (fully expanded on desktop, small box, phone screen, etc. )

[what it is looking like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzdJf.png)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer {
bottom: 0;
height: 2.5rem; 
color: black;
display: flex;
}

div {
width: 50%;
}

.footer #email {
  width:50% ;
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div>
  </div>
   <P id="email">
    valentinajnguyen@icloud.com
   </P>
</footer>
```

I find flex a great way to help me with "blank" content, and the % meassure will help it being responsive, i hope this helps.

Comment: How do I keep it towards the bottom of the page?

Comment: Either you use item-align: end; in the footer selector or the other content above it is going to push it down, it would be easier to know if we could see your whole html
Edit: you can also use on the footer selector position: fixed: and bottom: 0;

Comment: @ValentinaNguyen Check my solution. It has all answers to your question.

Comment: I added my whole code if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```css
@import ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

.page-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-left,
.content-right {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.content-left {
  width: 40%;
}

.content-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer span {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer .f-content:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 20px;
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 1px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fff;
  }
}

.footer .f-content:nth-child(3) {
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 1px;
    left: -13px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="content-left">
    <p>Digital Marketing Executive</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-right">
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="heading">Welcome to My Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <span class="f-content" id="email">valentinajnguyen@icloud.com</span>
      <span class="f-content" id="contact">(865) 242-8596</span>
      <span class="f-content" id="copyright">©2023 Valentina Nguyen. All right reserved.</span>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```